# characterization for induced subgraph of hamming graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I got interested into the property for induced subgraph of hamming graph lately. Specifically, I want to know the distance vertex coloring of a given induced subgraph of a hamming graph. There are some articles about the distance vertex coloring of hamming graph online. But I thought I need to collect as much as knowledge about induced subgraph of hamming graph as I can. After searching online, the two articles I have found about this are as follows.
A characterization of the Hamming graph by strongly closed subgraphs
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S019566980700193X#
and
characterizing subgraphs of hamming graphs.
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.20084/pdf.
Could anyone point to me some references in this direction? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: What exactly is a Hamming graph?  Is it the $n$-dimensional cube with vertices identified as binary strings of length $n$?

Comment: Travis, thanks for your quick response. Hamming graph is the Cartesian product of complete graphs that may be of varying sizes.